# How to apply integration to find position given an acceleration formula and time?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been self-studying Calc 1 and today started learning about integrals, antiderivatives, and Riemann sums. I think I have the concepts down pretty well, but I'm stuck on this problem:

A particle is moving with acceleration $a\left(t\right)=16\cdot t+4$. At time $t=0$ its position is $s\left(0\right)=7$ and its velocity is $v\left(0\right)=14$. What is its position at time $t=4$?

I'm not sure how to start the problem. I know once I get the ball rolling, i.e. get my initial equation cleaned up, I'll be able to solve via substitution, but I don't think I started it correctly. What I tried to do was find the antiderivative of $a(t)$ and substitute for $t$ afterwards, like so:

$v\left(t\right)=\int\left(16\cdot t+4\right)dt$

$v\left(t\right)=8\cdot t^2+4\cdot t+C$

$v\left(4\right)=8\cdot\left(4\right)^2+4\cdot\left(4\right)+C$

$v\left(4\right)=C+144$

I'm positive I've jumped too far ahead in the problem solving process, though, so if someone could help point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: You haven't used that $v(0)=14$. Use it to find $C$.

Comment: Hint: plug in v(0)! Solve for unknown constants and you're golden.